# Onion Pattern .Net Core Related Entities

Tags: asp.net-core, onion-architecture

I'm trying to understand Onion architecture pattern in .net core.  Given the Github example project below, how would you include related entities? For example, in the GamesController, how would you also return the related platform entities?  Since each service is bound to an entity repository

https://github.com/CubicleJockey/OnionPattern

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get a list of all games.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("all")]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return ExecuteAndHandleRequest(() => GameRequestAggregate.GetAllGamesRequest.Execute());
    }



    public class GameRequestAggregate : BaseRequestAggregate<Domain.Game.Entities.Game>, IGameRequestAggregate
        {

            public GameRequestAggregate(IRepository<Domain.Game.Entities.Game> repository, IRepositoryAggregate repositoryAggregate) 
                : base(repository, repositoryAggregate)  {}

            #region Implementation of IGameRequestAggregate

            private ICreateGameRequest createGameRequest;
            public ICreateGameRequest CreateGameRequest => createGameRequest ?? (createGameRequest = new CreateGameRequest(Repository, RepositoryAggregate));

            private IDeleteGameByIdRequest deleteGameByIdRequest;
            public IDeleteGameByIdRequest DeleteGameByIdRequest =>deleteGameByIdRequest ?? (deleteGameByIdRequest = new DeleteGameByIdRequest(Repository, RepositoryAggregate));

            private IGetAllGamesRequest getAllGamesRequest;
            public IGetAllGamesRequest GetAllGamesRequest => getAllGamesRequest ?? (getAllGamesRequest = new GetAllGamesRequest(Repository, RepositoryAggregate));

            #endregion
        }




public class GetAllGamesRequest : BaseServiceRequest<Domain.Game.Entities.Game>, IGetAllGamesRequest
    {
        public GetAllGamesRequest(IRepository<Domain.Game.Entities.Game> repository, IRepositoryAggregate repositoryAggregate) 
            : base(repository, repositoryAggregate) { }


        #region Implementation of IGetAllGamesRequest

        public GameListResponse Execute()
        {
            Log.Information("Retrieving Games List...");
            var gameListResponse = new GameListResponse();
            try
            {
                var games = Repository.GetAll()?.ToArray();

                if (games == null || !games.Any())
                {
                    var exception = new Exception("No Games Returned.");
                    Log.Error(EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_TEMPLATE, exception.Message);
                    HandleErrors(gameListResponse, exception, 404);
                }
                else
                {
                    gameListResponse = new GameListResponse
                    {
                        Games = games,
                        StatusCode = 200
                    };
                    var count = games.Length;
                    Log.Information("Retrieved [{Count}] Games.", count);
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

The linked repo is *highly* over-engineered, and frankly *naively* engineered at that. Creating multiple projects does not equal "onion architecture", and there's dependency bleed all over the place. The entire concept of onion architecture is to have *true* layers. Input flows in and out between the layers and there's no cross over. It looks like the contributor is making a stab at CQRS, but fails rather miserably.

As to your specific question, there's a fatal flaw in this particular setup in using repositories. As unfortunately far too many developers do, the contributor has failed to realize that when using an ORM like EF, that *is* your data layer. Creating a separate abstraction on top of that is only going to cause problems unless you replicate everything EF does, such as joins, change tracking, object fixup, etc. Of course, by the time you've done that, you've basically just re-implemented EF. Putting something like a simple repository between your app and EF, essentially serves to only limit what you can do with your data, which of course, in this case, is your issue of not being able to join in related entities without massive over-querying.

If you want to truly abstract your data dependency, the CQRS and microservice patterns are your best bet. CQRS is a very complex topic, but it essentially boils down to building "commands" that do specific things, along with an eye towards creating an event-driven model. I encourage you research the topic more, but I will say that the effort to setup it all up correctly really only makes sense in large, enterprise-scale applications. That's especially true given the rise of the microservices pattern.

Microservices are essentially tiny APIs. They're typically implemented as REST-based web APIs, but do not necessarily have to be. Regardless, the idea is that you have endpoints that perform specific tasks are return specific data. They should focus on a discrete unit of app functionality. For example, an ecommerce site might have a product service, cart service, a payment processing/checkout service, an order service, etc. Each component utilizes one or more of these microservices to accomplish some task. There's typically one or more API gateways involved to coordinate the activity of multiple microservices. That may sound a little complex, but it's actually rather easy to set up, especially if you're already familiar with building REST-based APIs. The hardest lift is coordinating the services to do a particular job. This pattern also presents a benefit of being highly-scalable. Since each microservice is discrete and abstract, you can easily load-balance and/or create clusters. And, in a cloud-environment, you scale up or scale down easily based on traffic. If your site is getting hammered in one area, you just spin up more instances of the microservices in play, and when traffic dies down, you spin them back down.

Finally, I'll leave you with advice I had to learn the hard way: start small. There's an impetus to want to do things "right", and therefore to implement all sorts of patterns and architectural styles, right from the start. The result of that is that you usually get stuck in pattern hell, and never actually *build* anything, i.e. you have a very complex setup that took you weeks or months to develop and nothing actually of real-world use to show for it.

Instead, build the smallest unit of functionality in the most straight-forward and simple way possible. Then, move on to the next. After each iteration, you should have something that actually *works*. You keep doing this until you have your core functionality built. It may not be pretty, but it does the job. Then, you refactor: if you've reused bits of code, factor those out. If you've got similar but slightly different code, find ways to generalize it first. As things, start to be abstracted, you may find the need to create class libraries and such. Over time, you may end up building a truly complex setup with all kinds of layers and abstractions, but that is 100% not where you start.